# AJAX Code For Uploading

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My html page for uploading has only two things on it: a file open button, and a Submit. It's no problem getting the open dialog up, but after the user clicks OK, where can I find the path string?

```
</td>
 <td style="width: 109.8pt; padding: .75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt" width="146">
 <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
 <p class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
 </td>
```

Does the php file below come with development tools, or is it part of default Windows javaScrpt?

action="upload.php"

Comment: We can't know what your PHP file does. You would have to show that. At any rate, it probably has nothing to do with neither Windows nor JavaScript

Comment: Do you know of any good PHP script, for uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Pekka is correct, this has nothing to do with either asp.net or javascript.  When you submit a file upload (whether it be in an asp.net app or php) there will be some standard Response information, some of which will be details on the selected file (filename, etc.).

A quick Google search brings up several open source PHP upload utilities, as well as file upload DOM references, such as:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/uploadtool/
2. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php
3. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

I'd recommend editing your question to exclude the asp.net tag and replace it with PHP.  That way more PHP developers will see your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code**

You have to make an "images" folder in the current directory and make two files : 
1: Index.php 2: upload.php

You will also get the image name in the **success** which can be used for saving image name in the database.

**1: Index.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
    </title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var imgName = "";
        $(function () {
            $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "upload.php",
                        type: "POST" ,
                        data: new FormData(this),
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                            imgName = data.path;
                            var pic = imgName;

                        },
                        error: function () {}
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic">
        <br>
         <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**2: Upload.php**

```
<?php

if (is_array($_FILES)) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'])) {
        $sourcePath = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = "./images/" .time(). $_FILES['pic']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)) {
            $imgPath['path']=$targetPath;
            echo json_encode($imgPath);
        }
    }
}
```